# Why does my ReadProcessMemory returns 0 when reading a game value? C++

Tags: c++, memory

Goodmorning,

I'm trying to read a value from Minecraft. It runs at 64 bit. Also the address is 100% correct because I can change it with Cheat Engine too and then it works. The address I try to get a value from is a float. I also turned my character set to multibyte and compiled it for 64 bit. Still it returns 0. Is there something wrong with my code? I appreciate the help.

This is the value read in Cheat Engine: 0.1000000015.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD pID;
DWORD result;
DWORD address = 0x206B06D319C;

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, "Minecraft");

    while (true)
    {
        if (hwnd == NULL)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Minecraft process not found.. Please start Minecraft!" << endl;
            hwnd = FindWindow(0, "Minecraft");
        }       
        else
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pID);
            HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
            if (handle == NULL)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "Minecraft process cannot be obtained.. Please try again!" << endl;
                handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
            }
            else
            {
                ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)0x206B06D319C, &result, sizeof(float), 0);
                cout << result << endl; // This returns 0 from what I understand this means the readprocess could not be completed.
            }
        }
        Sleep(250);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's a `float`, why is `result` a `DWORD`?

Comment: First step: check whether `ReadProcessMemory` succeeded by examining its return value. If it didn't, figure out what the error was.

Comment: @molbdnilo I changed it to a float still does return 0 anything from GetLastError I got 299 back. Can't find any information about that.

Comment: A quick google for "windows error 299" turned up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499- plus quite a few stackoverflow posts

Comment: Yeah, and no answer to my specific question believe me i searched for 6 hours.

Comment: as pointed out by @czs108 in their now deleted answer `DWORD` is 32-bits so your address `0x206B06D319C` will be truncated

Comment: What comment? I still don't have a solution what is going wrong?